# Current slide + nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an example. In the header there is a menu. Upon scrolling through pages (blocks), the text in the next menu-item (`li`) should be colored red.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yYJ3z/6/)

For example, click function on the menu:

```
$(".navigation li").click(function () {
        activeSection = $(this).index();
        $(".navigation li, .mobile-menu li").css({
            color: '#879996'
        });
        $(this).css({
            color: 'red'
        });
        scrollMeToSection();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check, if that's what you want: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yYJ3z/7/)

I've added some css-rules:

```
.header-bg .navigation li {
    color: #879996;
}
.header-bg .navigation li.current {
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

Also I've added `'current'` class to first `li`:

```
<li id="NavWho" class='current'>Rules</li>
```

And updated `scrollMeToSection` function:

```
function scrollMeToSection() {
    $('body').animate({
        scrollTop: ($(window).height() * activeSection)
    }, '1000', 'swing', function () {
        // can do something when finishes animating here.
        $('.navigation ul li').removeClass('current');
        $('.navigation ul li').eq(activeSection).addClass('current');
    });
}
```

Comment: Thnx for this simple code. Now I would know about .eq().

Comment: This isn't working because `$(window).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll')` event not firing if content scrolling without mousewheel. You should replace it with something else (e.g. `$(window).on('scroll')`)

Answer (score 0):

If you use bootstrap, there is [scrollspy plugin](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy), or [this single scroll spy plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/scrollSpy/)

Answer (score 0):

A jQuery plugin like http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints will help you with this.